# Tu parles bien français or tu parles français bien?

Tags: grammaire, adverbes

Which of the following is correct?

1. Tu parles français bien.
2. Tu parles bien français.

Answer (score 3):

The latter, "Tu parles bien français."

There are adverbs for which the order does not really matter, for instance: "Tu parles correctement français" or "Tu parles français correctement" but in this case "Tu parles français bien" would not work.

Comment: Note that adding another adverb changes things also: "Tu parles français assez bien" works much better already.

Comment: @LaurentS.The order matters too: *Tu parles assez bien français* vs. *Tu parles bien assez français*

Comment: @jlliagre Je n'ai pas compris ton commentaire. Pourrais-tu détailler ?

Comment: @Oreste *Assez bien* qualifie la qualité indépendamment de la quantité (niveau en français situé entre moyen et  bon) alors que *bien assez* qualifie la quantité indépendamment de la qualité (tu parles suffisamment, voire trop en français, sous-entendu : il faudrait que tu parles maintenant dans une autre langue).